# Save dynamic increment radio button selected value to data base

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save radio button selected value to the data base as if they ware not incriminated dynamically then that would have been no big deal to save, but as in my situation the ratio buttons are dynamically generated in a `html` table.

The below i have added a `html` code where it shoes only 3 set of radio button like same i have n number of radio button generated depending on data base fetch row s

What i want is i just want to save the value of radio button that are selected on submit. to Mysql

```
<table id="attendence_div" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0">
<tr align="left" style="background-color:#004080;color:White;">
            <td> Student Name</td>                        
            <td>Present</td>            
            <td>Absent</td>       
                <td>Leave</td>                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>ANITHA S</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present0" value="Present"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present0" value="Absent"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present0" value="Leave"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>ANITHA T C</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present1" value="Present"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present1" value="Absent"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present1" value="Leave"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>BINDU K V</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present2" value="Present"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present2" value="Absent"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Present2" value="Leave"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

C# Code

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string present = Present0.Checked;
    string absent = Present1.Checked;
      string Leave = Present2.Checked;

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO attendence(absent, present, Leave ) VALUES(@absent, @present,@Leave)"))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@absent", absent);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@present", present);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leave", Leave);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried  asp radioButtonList control

Comment: @FatihSert I am new to this i really dont know how to do that :( if u can help me out i would be very thank full to u

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can use the control

1 . You can add as a sub item under the radiobuttonlist in .aspx

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem>ColdFusion</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>Asp.Net</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>PHP</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

2 . other way you can add in your c# code

2 .1 Add control Definition in your .aspx

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"> </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

2 .2 you can add dynamically in c# code

```
RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(new ListItem ());
```

[Also check msdn document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

here my solution for your situation

**ASPX**

```
   <asp:Table runat="server" ID="table">
                <asp:TableHeaderRow BackColor="#004080" ForeColor="White">
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell runat="server" ID="header2" Text="Header2" Width="200px" />
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell runat="server" ID="header3" Text="Header3" Width="200px" />
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell runat="server" ID="Header4" Text="Header4" Width="200px" />
                </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            </asp:Table>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submit" OnClick="submit_Click" Text="submit" />
```

**C#**

```
 private const string radioButtonGroupNamePrefix = "radioButtonGroupName";
        private const string radioButtonIDPrefix = "radioButton";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeRadioButtonList();
        }

        private void InitializeRadioButtonList()
        {
          // you can fetch data here and then use.
          // for example returns 5 rows from database then you must change "for" syntax 
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)//rows count
            {
                var row = new TableRow();

                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    var cell = new TableCell();

                    var radioButton = new RadioButton();
                    radioButton.ID = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", radioButtonIDPrefix, i,j);
                    radioButton.Text = radioButton.ID;
                    radioButton.GroupName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", radioButtonGroupNamePrefix, i);//same gruop name for same row
                    cell.Controls.Add(radioButton);

                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }


        protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in Request.Form.AllKeys)
            {
                if (item.Contains(radioButtonGroupNamePrefix))
                {
                    var radioButton = (FindControl(item) as RadioButton);
                }
            }
            //TODO : DB operations
        }
```

Comment: Got ur point if possible can you give me a example for my code to insert data to db for above button click event

Comment: Sorry @Shaik not now because I'm writing phone it's too hard to write code .I will try to add example in 6 hour

Comment: sure but dont forget vl wait for u and thanks for the support

Comment: No problem but to be informed i have asked one more question today they suggested me the same and they have asked me to use repeaters i thought before doing that it is good u have a look ones exactly wat i want i can share my screen

Comment: @Shaik I added solution for your situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97972/discussion-between-shaik-and-fatih-sert).

Comment: the above is wat i exately wanted but how to define a row length depending on database row fetch

Comment: if u dont mind can i have some of ur time that would be more help full for me

Comment: Multiple controls with the same ID 'radioButton_0' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Comment: Sorry i fixed same id issue

Comment: and i have a quick question the radio button are generated but how to generate then depending on fetch if possible can you have a look i have created the same in the html and php ma b u vl get an idea wat am expecting